# Live USB doesn't start - GNU GRUB version 2.02

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, live-usb

When starting my laptop, the first and only screen I see is "GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9 Minimal BASH-like line ...". 
I can't access to BIOS, nor use a bootable usb flash drive. It doesn't read it.

This is the result of many unwise steps: 
I had ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 in dual boot. I reinstalled Windows 8, so the dual boot didn't start. I disabled fast and secure boot to use the usb flash drive to run Ubuntu, but it didn't start. I deleted the partitions of ubuntu from windows and used easyBCD. I did something wrong with this program and when I rebooted my laptop, I was stuck at that GRUB screen.

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you boot a windows install disk?